# SAMBA on exFAT partition, can't have write permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, exfat

I have an exFAT external disk, and I want to share its contents via Samba.

Everything works for for READING, but for writting I get a message saying I have no permissions.

This is my smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, XBMC)
netbios name = XBMCbuntu
dns proxy = no
name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
guest account = xbmc
load printers = no
show add printer wizard = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:*     %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
invalid users = root

[Movies]
path = /media/Movies
comment = Video's and Movies Folder
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall exfat-fuse exfat-utils
chmod -Rf 777 /media/Movies
```